# cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-whitelist does not change config.xml so it will be readded upon build

Tags: android, cordova, plugins

When I run

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

and then run

```
cordova build android
```

I get the following message:

> Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
>
> Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist@1" via npm
>   Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for android
>
> This plugin is only applicable for versions of cordova-android greater
>   than 4.0. If you have a previous platform version, you do *not* need
>   this plugin since the whitelist will be built in.

and then the build proceeds.

So cordova plugin rm is not removing the plugin as I never installed it, as it should?

## edit

Removing this plugin will make the webview blank. I expected it to accept any url, but it rejected everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what your question is here. In order to remove the plugin from the `config.xml` file, you'll need to add the `--save` flag to the `cordova plugin rm` call ([reference](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-cli/#cordova-plugin-command)):

```
cordova plugin rm <plugin-id> --save
```

Without the `--save` flag, the plugin is removed from the app, but not from the `config.xml` file.

So when you next call `cordova build` or `cordova prepare`, the script will look at your `config.xml` file and add any plugins that are specified there but not installed. So the plugin will be added back.

Comment: Hello! The question was if cordova plugin rm fails to remove the plugin so the files would be like it was never installed.

Comment: "The local copy of the plugin" is an interesting formulation. Where is the actual copy stored? I tried to change the source of a plugin, but the changes did never show up when I was using cordova build android and cordova run android.

Comment: Ack -- sorry for the confusion; I just cleaned up the answer. 

As an aside, I think the behavior to re-add missing plugins is newer in the `cordova build` script. I like that Cordova pulls down from npm what you need to get a successful build, but it does mean keeping `config.xml` up to date.

Comment: Thanks for the clean up answer! Do you know how to have the plugins recompiled? If I change the source of a downloaded plugin, those changes seems to be ignored.

Comment: Where are you making the changes? In the `/plugins` subdirectory of your app?

Comment: Yes, but nothing happens.

Comment: For short-term, experimental stuff, you could try doing a `cordova platform rm android` / `cordova platform add android` -- this should propagate the changes down to the `/platforms` subdirectory of your app. Longer term, you might want to consider forking the plugin, making the changes in your cloned source of the plugin project, and adding your local version of the plugin. You can add plugins via relative path, for example: `cordova plugin add ../my-whitelist`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126547/discussion-between-eb1-and-anders-linden).

Comment: It must be the "gradle deamon" that caches the files?